# GeckoMa process seems to consume lot of CPU

Tags: system-installation, kernel, cpu, process, memory-usage

I have been getting this weird problem lately, gecko process seems to consume lot of CPU processing , and this is becoming irritating , is there any fix for this and why is it happening ?

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   4454 atif      20   0 4202036 655248 181484 S  82.7   8.1  53:49.64 GeckoMa+ 
   1746 root      20   0   24.3g  96492  59060 R  55.1   1.2  39:53.31 Xorg     
   1877 atif      20   0 4727352 357880  92456 S  20.9   4.4   7:44.11 gnome-s+ 
  15959 atif      20   0 2741620 304772 105704 S  12.0   3.8   2:02.30 Isolate+ 
   3389 atif      20   0  436708  52336  37936 S   6.0   0.7   8:04.54 python3  
   1061 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   2.0   0.0   2:33.65 irq/148+ 
   5140 atif      20   0  830204  49108  37820 S   2.0   0.6   0:05.55 gnome-t+ 
  11009 atif      20   0   36.4g  84268  67616 S   1.3   1.0   0:25.86 webwork+ 
    957 www-data  20   0 1448184 144312  20224 S   1.0   1.8   0:17.73 apache2  
  20252 atif      20   0   20868   4276   3224 R   0.7   0.1   0:00.19 top      
   1922 atif      20   0  162916   5944   5724 S   0.3   0.1   0:01.48 at-spi2+ 
   2118 atif      20   0 1039496  22444   5556 S   0.3   0.3   0:05.80 snap-st+ 
 4454 atif      20   0 4202036 655248 181484 S  82.7   8.1  53:49.64 GeckoMa+ 
   1746 root      20   0   24.3g  96492  59060 R  55.1   1.2  39:53.31 Xorg     
   1877 atif      20   0 4727352 357880  92456 S  20.9   4.4   7:44.11 gnome-s+ 
  15959 atif      20   0 2741620 304772 105704 S  12.0   3.8   2:02.30 Isolate+ 
   3389 atif      20   0  436708  52336  37936 S   6.0   0.7   8:04.54 python3  
   1061 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   2.0   0.0   2:33.65 irq/148+ 
   5140 atif      20   0  830204  49108  37820 S   2.0   0.6   0:05.55 gnome-t+ 
  11009 atif      20   0   36.4g  84268  67616 S   1.3   1.0   0:25.86 webwork+
```

**Ubuntu version**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: GeckoMain is a mozilla process, and it might be a good idea to restart it, as it's been running for nearly 54 hours.

Comment: ohh, let me try that , it does stop sometimes but it has been happening frequently lately

Comment: Where is the version and type of Ubuntu in your question?

Comment: @David updated my answer

Comment: @mike there seem to be no avail

Comment: I've been having the same issue recently.

Comment: So..., we don't know which FF version it is. Is it uptodate?

Comment: yes , i do it regularly @mikewhatever , it is intermittent though, it happens sometimes and sometimes not, but when it does , my lappy sounds like pressure cooker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after roasting my **CPU** for weeks and exhausting by battery reserves, the issue was caused by **Mozilla** hardware acceleration settings, if you seem to be using it, or have put hardware acceleration off or you any custom settings, just resort to default ones, *i just changed mine to recommended settings and everything came back to normal!*